# Override browser `back` button functionality in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material-stepper, back-button-control

I have a page in my `Angular` App where it uses a `stepper`. When the user is for example on step 3, the first logical thing he will do to get back to the previous step (step 2) is to click on the `back button`. But obviously, he will get redirected to the previous page.

So, I would be able to set the `stepper` to previous on back click instead of redirecting the user to last page and when he is on **step 1** redirect him to last page.

I was trying to use `@HostListener` by casting `this.stepper.previous();` (function which set the stepper to previous) but while the action is `catched` the function is not executed and the page is anyway redirected back.

**So how can i prevent the page to get redirected on back button click?**

Here is what I've tried:

```js
@HostListener( 'window: popstate', ['$event'])
onPopState(event: Event): void {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("BACK PRESSED")
  this.stepper.previous();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There two points here in your question:

1. If you want `disable` `back` button for whole application or more than one component
2. If you want just `disable` `back` button for a specific component

For the #1 requirement, I think the better way is to implement a `Guard` and apply it on the required `routes`. But, if the #2 is desired, using `onPopState()` looks OK, but it seems that you missed using `LocationStrategy`  and `history.pushState()`, So try this:

```js
import { LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root'
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    private location: LocationStrategy
  ) {
    history.pushState(null, null, window.location.href);
    // check if back or forward button is pressed.
    this.location.onPopState(() => {
        history.pushState(null, null, window.location.href);
        this.stepper.previous();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, It seems that doesn't exist anymore. replace it with this: `window.location.href`

Comment: i wan't to disable backbutton on showing an alert box. ie., based on some condition like 

     showAlert ==true,   i want to re enable backbutton on closing backbutton ?is there any way to acheive it? this question also asks same
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67682485/angular-disable-enable-back-button