# Angular Disable / Enable Back Button

Tags: angular, browser, history, back, pushstate

What I want to achieve is to disable and re-enable the back button at a certain moment of time.
I used the following method to disable the back button:

```
disableBackButton() {
        history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
        this.locationStrategy.onPopState(() => {
          history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
        })
}
```

However, I don't know how to implement a function to "re-enable" the back button.

Comment: what is your html code? and when the button is going to be disabled?

Comment: Let's assume I have a button that calls toggleEnableBackButton() that must disable/enable the button whenever it is clicked.

Comment: what is your html code... of button which you wanna disable..?

Comment: The button I want to disable/enable is the browser back button and the button used to toggle between enable/disable is a basic button that looks like this 
<button (click)="toggleEnabled()">Toggle</button>

Comment: @ViorelOnica did you figureout answer to your question then please post answer?

Answer (score 0):

Ok! take `[disabled]="disabled==0"` inside button html and define disabled:any property in ts file... then inside simply use

```
 this.disabled = 0; // when you want it to be disabled...
 this.disabled=1; // when you want it to be enabled...
```

in your function.